# Bootstrap carousel with HTML5 banner content - how to pause animations until user is viewing that slide?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, banner, tween

I am creating a digital portfolio that is showcasing HTML5 banners. I am building this with a foundation of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and utilizing the Bootstrap carousel for my users to flip through different HTML5 banner creatives. I have used iframe to display these banners in the carousel and it works, here is my code:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <iframe src="/digital-portfolio/banners/1/300x600" width="300" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <iframe src="/digital-portfolio/banners/2/300x600" width="300" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <iframe src="/digital-portfolio/banners/3/300x600" width="300" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The issue with this is that the banner animations play all the way through regardless of what slide you are currently on. So, for the second and third banners, once the user clicks through to view those banners they have already finished playing their animation and are resting on the last frame. I could loop the animation, but the ideal functionality is that the animation does not begin until the user is on that slide. Here is an example of HTML5 banner JavaScript code that I am working with. They all typically use [NanoTween](http://doc.nanotween.com/net/edecker/tween/NanoTween.html) for their animations.

```
var loading = getElement("id", "loading");
var banner = getElement("id", "banner");
var clickTagButton = getElement("id", "clickTagButton");
var seq1 = getElement("id", "seq1");
var seq1_BW = getElement("id", "seq1_BW");
var seq1_mask = getElement("id", "seq_mask1");
var copy1 = getElement("id", "copy1");
var copy3 = getElement("id", "copy3");
var copy4 = getElement("id", "copy4");
var name1 = getElement("id", "name1");
var name2 = getElement("id", "name2");
var btn = getElement("id", "btn");
var seq2 = getElement("id", "seq2");
var seq2_BW = getElement("id", "seq2_BW");
var seq3 = getElement("id", "seq3");
var seq3_BW = getElement("id", "seq3_BW");

function init() {

setTimeout(function() {
    startAnimation();
}, 100);
}

function startAnimation() {
loading.parentNode.removeChild(loading);
banner.style.visibility = "visible";

var seqSpeed = 0.15;
var seq1_delay = 3;
var seq2_delay = 6;
var seq3_delay = 7.1;
var fadeSpeed = 0.3;
var fadeSpeed_prod = 1;

seq1.playbackRate = 1.3;
seq2.playbackRate = 1;
seq3.playbackRate = 1;

NanoTween.delayedCall(0.1, function() {
    seq1.play();
});
NanoTween.delayedCall(3.5, function() {
    seq1.pause();
});

NanoTween.to(seq1, fadeSpeed, {
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: 3.1
});

NanoTween.to(copy1, fadeSpeed, {
    clip: "rect(306px,300px,529px,15px)",
    ease: "linear",
    delay: 3.1
});

//frame mask animation from top left
NanoTween.to(name1, fadeSpeed, {
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: 3
});
NanoTween.to(seq1_mask, fadeSpeed_prod, {
    transform: "translate(848px, 150px) rotate(45deg)",
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: 5.2
});
NanoTween.to(seq1_BW, fadeSpeed_prod, {
    transform: "translate(-598px, 597px) rotate(-45deg)",
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: 5.2
});
NanoTween.to(copy1, fadeSpeed, {
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: 5.2
});

NanoTween.delayedCall(5.2, function() {
    seq2.play();
});
//NanoTween.delayedCall(seq1_delay + 3.7, function(){seq2.pause();});


NanoTween.to(seq2, fadeSpeed, {
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: 6.2
});


//frame mask animation from top left
NanoTween.delayedCall(seq2_delay, function() {
    seq3.play();
});

NanoTween.to(copy3, fadeSpeed, {
    clip: "rect(235px, 274px, 424px, 16px)",
    ease: "linear",
    delay: seq3_delay
});
NanoTween.to(name2, fadeSpeed, {
    opacity: 1,
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: seq3_delay
});
NanoTween.to(copy4, fadeSpeed, {
    transform: "translate(0px, 0px)",
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: seq3_delay
});
NanoTween.to(copy4, fadeSpeed * 2, {
    opacity: 1,
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: seq3_delay
});
NanoTween.to(seq3, fadeSpeed, {
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "ease-out",
    delay: seq3_delay += seqSpeed
});
NanoTween.to(btn, fadeSpeed, {
    clip: "rect(0px,209px ,45px ,0px)",
    ease: "linear",
    delay: seq3_delay + 0.5
});

}

function getElement(element, id) {
var mc;
switch (element) {
    case "id":
        mc = document.getElementById(id);
        break;

    case "class":
        mc = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
        break;
}

return mc;
}


window.onload = function() {
init();
};
```

Is there a way to initialize the animation to start once the user is on that slide, or potentially trigger the animation from clicking the carousel controls?

Here is an image of what the slider looks like:
[image: Example of HTML5 banner carousel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear where your NanoTween code is being run. I'm assuming that is being run inside the iframe. First of all, you need to know when a particular slide is active. That can be done by hooking into the carousel events in your parent page. There are two events, slide.bs.carousel which is triggered when transitioning to a new slide, and slid.bs.carousel which is triggered when the new slide is active.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        // stop any active slides
        $('iframe[src*="play"]',this).each(function() {
           $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').split('#')[0]+"#stop");
        });
        $('iframe',e.relatedTarget).each(function() {
           $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').split('#')[0]+"#play");
        });
    });

});
```

Once you know that a slide is active, you can notify the iframe by adding a hash to the end of the url. Inside each iframe, you would start or stop the animation when the hash changes:

```
function init() {

    /* remove this
    setTimeout(function() {
        startAnimation();
    }, 100);
    */

    window.onhashchange = function(){ 
        switch(location.hash.slice(1)) {
           case 'play':
              startAnimation();
              break;
           case 'stop':
              stopAnimation();
              break;
        }
    };

    window.onhashchange();
}
```

Lastly, set the hash on the slide which is initially active

```
<div class="item active">
    <iframe src="/digital-portfolio/banners/1/300x600#play" width="300" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```